Spinor bundles and spin structures
I want to check my understanding of the relationship between spinor bundles and spin structures.
So, as far as I understand, given a principal $\operatorname{SO}(n)$-bundle $\pi : P_{SO} \rightarrow M$ over a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, a spin structure is a pair $(P_{spin}, \phi)$ where $\hat{\pi} :  P_{spin} \rightarrow M$ is a principal $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$-bundle over $M$ and $\phi : P_{spin} \rightarrow P_{SO}$ is an equivariant 2-fold cover map such that $\pi \circ \phi = \hat{\pi}$ and $\phi(p\cdot g) = \phi(p)\cdot\rho(g)$, $\forall p \in P_{spin}, g \in \operatorname{Spin}(n)$ where $\rho : \operatorname{Spin}(n) \rightarrow \operatorname{SO}(n) $ is the covering map.
After understanding this definition I wanted to see how a spin structure defined a spinor bundle so I went to the wikipedia article on spinor bundles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle) from which I understood the following:
Given the spin connection one can define an associated bundle to $ \hat{\pi} :  P_{spin} \rightarrow M$  which would be $\pi_S : S \rightarrow M$ where $S = (P_{spin} \times \Delta_n)/G $  is the set containing all equivalence classes $[p, s]_{\sim_G}$  under the equivalence relation
$$\forall p \in P_{spin}, s \in \Delta_n, p \sim_G s\ \text{iff}\ \exists g \in \operatorname{Spin}(n)\ \text{such that}\  p \rightarrow p' = p\cdot g\ \text{and}\ s \rightarrow s' = g^{-1}\cdot s$$
where $ \Delta_n $ is the $n$-dimensional Hilbert space of spinors.
Then we can define spinors as sections of this spinor bundle. Is my understanding correct?

You don't need a spin connection to define $S$, just a spin structure. As for your equivalence relation, it's a little bit unclear and the expression $g^{-1}\cdot s$ doesn't make sense without the appropriate interpretation, but the idea is essentially correct. I would instead say the following:
Let $\kappa : \operatorname{Spin}(n) \to U(\Delta_n)$ be the complex spin representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ and set $S = P_{spin}\times_{\kappa}\Delta_n = (P_{spin}\times\Delta_n)/\sim$ where $(p, s) \sim (p\cdot g, \kappa(g^{-1})s)$ for all $p \in P_{spin}$, $s \in \Delta_n$, and $g \in \operatorname{Spin}(n)$. With this equivalence relation, we have $[(p\cdot g, s)] = [(p, \kappa(g)s)]$. The complex spinor bundle is the vector bundle $\pi_S : S \to M$ where $\pi_S([p, s]) = \hat{\pi}(p)$. Its sections are called spinor fields (or just spinors).
